# ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") generates Run-Time error '9' Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a userform to input a new row (first row after headers).

The userform contains 6 fields of which 4 are combobox (lists) and 2 text box.

When I run the code it gets stuck at: `Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ssheet As Worksheet

    Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    nr = ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row + 1

    ssheet.Cells(nr, 1) = Me.tbNAME
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 2) = Me.cmbStatus
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 3) = Me.cmbFunds
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 4) = Me.cmbDD
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 7) = Me.cmbDistributor
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 8) = Me.tbComments

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.tbDate = Date

    For Each blah In [StatusList]
        Me.cmbStatus.AddItem blah
    Next blah

    For Each blah In [FundsList]
        Me.cmbFunds.AddItem blah
    Next blah

    For Each blah In [DDList]
        Me.cmbDD.AddItem blah
    Next blah

    For Each blah In [DistributorList]
        Me.cmbDistributor.AddItem blah
    Next blah

End Sub
```

Comment: ThisWorkbook (the one containing the code) doesn't have a "Sheet1"?

Comment: Yes it does have a Sheet1 also called Master Log, I tried both solutions still nothing unfortunately :(

Comment: If it's called "Master Log" it's not called "Sheet1"! `Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Log")` The sheet code name is different from the tab name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the line:

```
Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Make sure `"Sheet1"` is actually the name of your sheet on your Workbook

Per your comment you can use:

`Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` or `Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Log")`

And for the following line:

```
nr = ssheet.Cells(ssheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed the name of my Master Log (Sheet1) into Sheet1. now the debugger says that the error is in the following line:

nr = ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row + 1

Comment: @SJR nice catch

Comment: solved with the xlup and not x1up sorry guys so stupid! thank you so much for your help!!!!